# solaris svm and raid5 : a way for expand on fly?

Tags: solaris, raid, svm

I know two methods for expand raid5 on solaris svm using UFS
one is [this](http://thegeekdiary.com/solaris-volume-manager-svm-growing-raid-5-metadevices-online/)
another is to replace disk by disk,suppose i want to remove old
small disk and replace with bigger disk
using this procedure

```
devfsadm
cfgadm -c configure sata2/0
format -d c0t5d0
metadb -a -f c0t5d0s2
metareplace -e myraid c0t4d0s2 c0t5d0s2
metadb -d c0t4d0s2
cfgadm -c unconfigure c0t4d0s2
```

I have replaced all disks with the method above and
my raid5 is online and ok
as metastat said
But after give

```
metadevadm -vr
```

and

```
growfs -M /raid /dev/md/rdsk/d44
```

The SIZE is the same as raid with old disks
and this is wrong because i replaced
disks with bigger disks.
On linux is really easy to replace
raid5 disk on fly and grow the raid5
(mdadm fail,add,grow,then pvresize..)
on fly,i miss something on solaris svm?
The first method is also good(concatenate+growfs)
but i want to replace disks old(small) with new(big).
Please don't answer zfs,for "study" reason i'm on ufs+svm

Comment: This way is not possible with this configuration as far as I know. You need to add extra disks to the RAID5to expand it. The metadevadm commnad updates only the device id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been awhile since I've had to touch SVM, but I'm inclined to agree with BitsOfNix that it's not possible to do what you are trying to do.  Memory is that you can only do what you're trying to do with RAID 1 on SVM.

Did you verify that `metastat` sees that the blocksizes have changed for the larger disks and the "RAID device?"

I think you're also missing a step prior to your growfs.  Memory is that you need to expand the slice of "RAID device" prior to the growfs.  And with RAID1 on SVM, then a metasync for the mirroring?  You might need to do something similar for RAID5 on SVM.

You mention doing this for a "study," but I'm not sure it's fair to ding SVM compared to mdadm since SVM was created and used in a different time to meet a different need.

Comment: yes with format i use 100% of disk large